# Nuxt 2, my row selection is not showing all rows

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

My Vue 2 code has an issue with selecting the number of rows to display in the table. It works for 5 and 10 rows, but when 25 rows are selected, only 10 rows are displayed. I don't know why this is happening.

```
 <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="paginatedItems" :single-select="singleSelect" item-key="name" show-select
          class="tableBasic" :disable-pagination="rowsPerPage === -1">
        </v-data-table>
```

```
<v-select v-model.number="rowsPerPage" :items="tableItems" label="Rows per page" solo></v-select>
```

```
tableItems: ['5', '10', '25', '100'],
      totalPages: 0,
      totalRegister: 0,
      rowsPerPage: 5,
      page: 1,
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.items = dados.data.list
    this.totalRegister = dados.data.totalRegister;
    this.totalPages = dados.data.totalPages;
    this.updatePagination();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dados.data.totalRegister))
  },
  computed: {
    paginatedItems() {
      const startIndex = (this.page - 1) * parseInt(this.rowsPerPage);
      const endIndex = startIndex + parseInt(this.rowsPerPage);
      return this.items.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    rowsPerPage(newRowsPerPage) {
      this.page = 1;
      this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRegister / newRowsPerPage);
    },
    items() {
      this.totalRegister = this.items.length;
      this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRegister / parseInt(this.rowsPerPage));
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.totalRegister = this.items.length;
    this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRegister / parseInt(this.rowsPerPage));
  },
}
```